# inline assembly in lldb expression evaluation?

Tags: lldb

I try to use inline assembly in LLDB's expression and it does not seem to work. As a toy example I run on ARM:

```
(lldb) expr  __asm__ __volatile__("mov r0, 4");
(lldb) register read
General Purpose Registers:
        r0 = 0x00000003
```

In reality I need to access the special CP15 c13 Software Thread ID registers and could not find other way of doing it within LLDB - so an idea here will be appreciated. I thought of using

```
expr  __asm__ __volatile__("MRC p15, 0, r0, c13, c0, 3");
```

It runs, but has no effect on the content of r0.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression that writes to a register won't actually change register state.  Before running an expression, lldb saves the register state away, and then it runs your expression, then restores the register state when it is done.  In almost all cases, you don't want whatever change was made to the registers in order to run some complex expression to get inherited by the program as it continues, or it will just crash.

If you need to change register state explicitly, then you have to use `register read`.

I know that wasn't the point of your exercise, this comment is more to explain why that approach didn't work.

Comment: Thanks Jim for the clarification. Did you mean "register write"? Also, is there a way to change PC like that?

Comment: Arg, yes, "register write".  You can change the pc by "reg write pc" - "pc" being an alias for whatever register is the program counter on your architecture.  Or you can use "thread jump" which allows you to specify the target by address, offset or file & line.  I'm sure you know what you are doing, but I feel duty-bound to point out that - particularly with things like ARC in the mix - jumping the program counter around can be very dangerous to your program's health...

Comment: Thanks again. So back to my original question: assembly does work, but can I make it useful? I mean i need to write an instruction that will move the result to something I can access from lldb?As you've explained, registers are restored, so where can I put the result I retrieve with MRC?

Comment: If you can find a place to stick the result in memory, then you could use "memory read" to get it back out again.